# How to show vertical line between multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

How to show vertical line between single and multiple lines of text as shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `border-left` property should solve this. Just wrap your lines inside a div.

```css
div {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting them in a wrapper with `border-left: 1px solid black;`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ofvajLa/

Answer (score 1):

You can show vertical line like Following:

```css
.test {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.test:last-child{
  border-left:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="test">
  <p>Bar</p>
 </div>
 <div class="test">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <p>Text 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ofvajLa/1/)**